# async function not workin

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

im trying to use async function to consume my api, but it simply doesent work, it didnt even console log anything, here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
import Profile from './Profile'
import api from '../services/api';




//import Home from './Mainpage'
const {heigth, width} = Dimensions.get('window')
```

here is just styles

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:"flex-end",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
  },
  PlaceContainer:{
    width: '100%',
    maxHeight:200,
    
  },
  button:{
    width:"10px",
    height:"10px"
  },
  title:{
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize: 20
  },
  place:{
    width:width -40 ,
    padding:20,
    maxHeight:200,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#0ff'
  },
  separator:{
    flex: 1,
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
  }
})
```

here I created a class  to make everything

```
export default class Dermatologistas extends Component{
  state ={
    MessageError: null,
    users: []
  }
```

that is not working, it isnt even console logging

```
    getUserList = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get('/auth/list');

      const { users } = response.data;

      this.setState({ users });
    } catch (response) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error });
    }
  };
```

just rendered to test

```
    render(){
    const users = this.state.users
```

in this console.log it return Array []

```
    console.log(users)
    return(
      <View>
        {this.state.users.map(user => (
          <View key={user._id} style={{marginTop: 15}}>
            <Text>{user.title}</Text>
            <Text>{user.speciality}</Text>
            </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: where you are calling getUserList ?

Answer (score 1):

Where's the call to getUserList?
Also, to your get method you should include the promise method then() which followed by a catch() method.

To summarize, your call should look like that:

```
fetch(url)
.then(function() {

})
.catch(function() {

});
```